# Simulator responds with "voice not recognized"

Tags: actions-on-google

When using the simulator in the Actions Console, I get the response:
"Since your voice wasn’t recognized, I can’t do that right now. Check the Voice Match settings in the Google Home app."

The account under which I am developing has no devices registered, intentionally.  This account is used specifically and only for development.

Why does the simulator respond like this, and how can I fix it?  The account has no "Google Home app".

I have another (personal) account which I've used to develop the Action initially.  The simulator works fine there.  Now I'm trying to move the development to an "official" corporate account, and the simulator fails completely.

Comment: Yeah, well... I now get the same thing on my other account, which was working perfectly fine a couple of days ago.  Must be either a Google failure, or some new, unannounced requirement.  Hard to tell because they have no status for AoG.

Comment: I've figured out it has something to do with account linking.  I am sending the "actions.intent.SIGN_IN" intent because the account isn't linked, and I get this message.

When it was working last week, it was on a browser that was signed in and therefore linked.  Now it won't send me to an authentication screen.

Comment: I'm also getting this error. To confirm, does it work for one of your accounts? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100444/getting-a-voice-match-error-when-trying-to-call-actions-on-google-signin-helper

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm I'm getting exactly the same occurrence here. 
Doesn't matter what device type is selected as being used. 
Similarly was working fine a couple of days ago.
Looks like Google has broken something with account linking and the Actions on Google Simulator.
I did however read somewhere that best practice you should be delivering some functionality that does not require account linking. That way you will still get explore ratings from users who visit your assistant but refuse to sign in.
However that doesn't fix the core issue of testing functionality that requires sign-in using Actions console simulator.

Comment: Yes, it looks like all my responses have:
 "payload": {
      "user": {
        "locale": "en-US",
        "userVerificationStatus": "GUEST"
      },
even though I am (obviously) signed in to the simulator and should therefore get a "VERIFIED" user response.  This can only be a Google bug afaict.